# Can't open file "django-admin.py": No such file or directory -- Mac OSX

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I have just done a fresh install of Python 2.7 and Django 1.6.5.

Entering into python in the terminal and using `import Django` and `django.VERSION` yields:

`(1, 6, 5, 'final', 0)`

But when I attempt to run `python django-admin.py startproject myproject`, I get the following:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

There doesn't seem to be a ton of info available on how to rectify this in a Mac, and the Django docs don't offer much assistance other that "maybe try a symlink".

Can someone help me solve this error?

EDIT: Here is the result of running `echo $PATH`

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: You should follow the django instructions exactly ;)

Comment: I was following the Tango with Django instructions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try running without `python`

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

**Explanation:**
It's because `django-admin.py` is added in one of the bin folders. Also, `python` expects a file path.

Comment: Added the explanation in the answer.

Comment: Much obliged. Will accept when the time limit hits.

Comment: Urgh, I've wasted 20 minutes trying to fix that with a symlink, and all I had to do was drop the python.  Thanks! (Symlink didn't work as it was trying to pull that python ^^ path first, so failed before it got to it, I think?)